# Fill hole and make manifold?

Tags: 3d-printing

I'm trying to fill a hole in a model I found online and I can't for the life of me figure out how to make it manifold. I'm using the F key to create a face around the edges of the hole. I tried to use the Solidify modifier, the merge by distance tool and to just extrude but nothing works. Probably a noobie question but I would be very grateful if you can answer me! Linked is a gif just so you can see the hole I'm trying to fill

[image]

Comment: Should work. However, you would have to delete the vertices behind it. See: [What is non-manifold geometry?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry)

Comment: are you sure the geometry around the hole is otherwise manifold when you start?  In particular, are there any overlapped vertices or extra/interior faces?